# Facebook Like plugin not showing faces even with "data-show-faces" set to true

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

Trying to add a Facebook Like button with the option "Show Faces" set to true. The problem I'm facing is that the faces don't show - only the names of friends who liked the page.

My code:

```html
<div
    class="fb-like"
    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Starbucks/"
    data-width="300"
    data-layout="standard"
    data-action="like"
    data-size="large"
    data-share="true"
    data-show-faces="true"
    data-kid-directed-site="false"
></div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Same here. Facebook SDK simply drives me nuts. If your code works now by some miracle it's a given it will break in 90 days.